# How to shutdown a luks encrypted server if not unlocked in 5 minutes?

Tags: linux, debian, luks, initramfs

I have a Debian server with an encrypted luks partition and I would like to run the following command before switch_Root

`shutdown -H +5`

I tried to put a script in/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top but the `shutdown` command is not working in initramfs. It says "command not found".

So I tried the `halt` command but it does not support scheduling. Is it possible to execute `halt` command with 5 minutes delay like I can with the `shutdown` command?

How can I automatically shutdown my server if the luks partition is not unlocked in 5 minutes?

Comment: Well, you can do your own scheduling - by running `halt` or `poweroff` in the background and terminating it once `cryptsetup` succeeds. Or, you can turn the problem around and run `timeout cryptsetup` to terminate cryptsetup after timeout, then poweroff or not depending on the exit code. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this for Debian specifically as I don't use Debian anymore.

Comment: @frostschutz how can i schedule `halt` or `poweroff`? I mean once I run the `halt` command the system shutdown immediately.

Comment: `busybox poweroff` has a `-d SEC` delay option for these, so you can `poweroff -d 300 &` - and then kill it after cryptsetup. -- But it may be that Debian initramfs is not providing you the busybox variant of poweroff. Then maybe `sleep 300 && poweroff &` would do, and it won't poweroff if you kill sleep.

Comment: @frostschutz I create a script with `sleep 300 && poweroff &` command and I put it in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top` but each time I run `sudo update-initramfs -u` my system shutsdown and does not generate the new image. Any workaround to this issue?

Comment: Did you follow the correct format for boot scripts as described in [the initramfs tools manpage](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs-tools.7.en.html)? Otherwise it will be executed on image generation. You'll also have to kill it when cryptsetup succeeds... alternatively put additional conditions between sleep and poweroff.

Comment: @frostschutz Thank you very much! Now it's working!